# Django template, send two arguments to template tag and return safe html value is there possible?

Tags: django, templates

im passing 2 values

```
{% checkdatainicio data.one data.two %} and my return is: '<span style="color:#bdc3c7">'+data+"</span>"
```

i want to return it safe in html

Comment: Did you implement `checkdatainicio` yourself? Can you add the source?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create an inclusion tag (or should be if you have not tried).  They are very useful.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags